# Add search filter on google input textfield

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, google-search

I want to add filter on input textfield

For example, If i Want to search **big data**

Add these filter **newer: 2014, language: Chinese ,type: blog**

Is it possible to search with those filter ?

I don't want to add filter with mouse click  and select some webforms

If so, how to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just [type directly in the url](http://moz.com/ugc/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters) bar. For example:

```
google.com#q=trends&lr=lang_zh-CN&as_qdr=y&site=blogsearch
```

**Update**
They've changed this since that blog post was made. Now you want to use # instead of ? in the query.

Some Tips:

- Set up a bookmark to the url with all of the options you want already
  typed out and just change what you need (you can use the regular input
  from here). You can choose weather or not you'd rather leave out the q
  parameter in order to have a default search query.
- To find the initial URL parameters you want, use the
  [advanced search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) dialog (found under settings in the bottom right
  of the page). The resulting url will have them (mixed in with a bunch 
  of garbage which you should remove).